# Erro na Classe PDO do PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Galera estou tentando usar a classe PDO em um dos meus sistemas e está aparecendo este erro, sendo que a classe PDO já está instalada.

```
Fatal error: Class 'PDO' not found in /home/dfmedica/public_html/cursos/classes/BD.class.php on line 9
```

Classe de conexão:

```
<?php
class BD{
    private static $conn;

    public function __construct(){}

    public static function conn(){
        if(is_null(self::$conn)){
            self::$conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.HOST.';dbname='.BD.'', ''.USER.'', ''.PASS.'');
        }

        return self::$conn;
    }
}
?>
```

OBS: Os dados de acesso ao banco estão corretos, pois já testei.

Comment: Acrecescenta estas duas linhas ao teu php.ini: "`extension="pdo.so" 
extension="pdo_mysql.so"`"

Comment: Não funcionou :(

Comment: Versão do php e o sistema operacional? a extensão aparce instalado no phpinfo()?

Comment: aparece sim veja no print: http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/1297401/3f6302ee54f289987312b44d80211777

Comment: Coloca o código que está usando, ou seja o `new PDO(...)` coloca desde o inicio do arquivo.

Comment: @rray veja a pergunta, editei colocando minha classe de conexão.

Comment: A extensão do PDO está habilitada no seu php.ini?